# How do I interpret this Facebook API upgrade notice

Tags: facebook-graph-api

My confusion possibly stems from a knowledge gap with Graph APIs in general, but Facebook's dashboard, terminology, phrasing, and docs certainly aren't helping - I've Googled thoroughly and haven't got any closer to understanding what's required.

I've tried to break down the overall question as best as I can into parts with screenshots for reference.

This is what I see in my Facebook developer dashboard:
[image]

**Question 1:** 
What are the numbers in the green rectangles?

**Question 2:**
What does it mean by "90-day changes"? 90 days from what point? Now or from October 29, 2019? Or something else altogether?

**Question 3:**
I've read this bit about a dozen times and it still doesn't make sense. There's no link to point me to anything here and the info icon next to "Change" is not clickable.

> Use the Messenger Use Case from Business Use Case Rate Limit framework to replace the current rate limit on Messenger API. This change applies to all APIs listed under Messenger Use Case.

What's actually needed to be done here?

**Question 4:**
The bit in the red rectangle reads:

> Add expired status for GET me/permissions, in addition to granted or declined.

Is this saying that FB have added this as part of their `GET` response or is it saying *I* need to add this in my request?

I clicked on the link for `GET {user-id}/permissions` and it takes me here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/permissions/, where I see this:
[image]

**Question 5:**
This one's related to Question 4. 'Parameters' - are they request or response parameters?

**NOTE:** I've checked the code in my application and I'm not explicitly calling any of these endpoints. The closest thing I could spot is the following line that makes use of the `react-native-fbsdk` package:

```
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email'])
```

I'm guessing it's probably a simple case of upgrading this package, but **the questions above still remain**.

Comment: 1. That’s the call value from the column before, broken down for the specific API calls. 2. From the day they where announced. This is mainly in reference to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes 3. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting/#buc-rate-limits 4. Addition on the API side, so developers can determine when they are dealing with a case of Data Access Expiration. 5. In that place it’s a request parameter.

Comment: @04FS Thanks for that. Regarding (1), what do you mean by call ‘value’? For (4), is it a change on the API side as part of a request or response? Because if it’s a change in response structure, my requests should still work without upgrading, correct?

Comment: Sorry, volume, not value. (4) is first and foremost about a change in how access to user data works. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/auth-vs-data#data-access-expiration

Comment: @04FS So for (4), does that just amount to me checking if access has expired based on response from the API?

Comment: Have you got any news on this? I've encountered the same problem with `GET {user-id}/permissions`. Still can't figure out where the call comes from, neither in my code nor the facebook sdk I'm using explicitly make this

Comment: @ThànhChungBùi Honestly I did this so long ago I can’t even remember.